# Custom object scoping with Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Very simple question here but I'm struggling to find any info on it. I've got a very simple parent/child hierarchy...

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    [Dependency]
    public IChild Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    [Dependency]
    public IParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

...and my container registrations are exactly what you'd expect:

```
this.Container.RegisterType<IParent, Parent>();
this.Container.RegisterType<IChild, Child>();
```

When the container creates a parent instance it automatically creates and injects a new instance of the child but how do I inject the parent reference into that child?

Basically I'm trying to find the Unity equivalent of Ninject's `InScope` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would constructor injection solve this problem for you?

```
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public IChild Child { get; set; }

    public Parent(IChild child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        this.Child = child;
    }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public IParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The `IChild` in the constructor is resolved by Unity without the `[Dependency]` decoration.

Comment: It would in this case, but the whole point I'm using custom scoping is so that I don't have to pass around interfaces all down my object hierarchy. It's not a big deal in the simple case I've provided, of course, but I could see it blowing out in a larger application. Other DI frameworks support it, I'd be surprised if Unity doesn't have some mechanism itself.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Are you looking for something like the Unity PerResolveLifetimeManager?  It reuses instances on a per-resolve basis, as described on the msdn at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx.  I think it would look something like `this.Container.RegisterType<IParent, Parent>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());`